# Find out who installed SQL server - they forgot to add other logons

Tags: sql-server, sql, permissions

We have a site where one of our team of techies installed SQL Server 2012. They forgot to add our administrators group as sysadmins so only they can access SQL - everyone else gets "Access Denied"

How can we find out who installed SQL, or who is a SQL Administrator so we can ask them to correct their fault?

I have domain admin rights to the server.

Comment: Another option would be to use the same procedure used to recover from lost administrator access: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx)

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly! If you post that as an answer I can mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have admin rights to the server you can use the same procedure used to recover access when system administrators are locked out.

MSDN: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx)